# Implementing NodeEntity base class, implications of the Labels

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I would like to have following kind of base class for every inherited node classes.

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class NodeEntityBase {

// id is not used with advanced mapping spring-data-neo4j.
@GraphId
protected Long id;

@Indexed(unique = true)
@NotNull
protected String appId;
```

....

But If I implement that, Spring-data-neo4j will create NodeEntityBase label for every node. I don't really use this label for anything and I am worried whether this will become performance issue later (or some other issues). I know there is limit 2 billions (int max) for the entries in the label index, which may become a problem, so for that reason I would like to fix this.

Is there good workaround or design to achieve this? I would very much like to have base class(es) where I can put properties (like timestamp created, etc) that almost every node inherits. I know I could use interfaces (I have not tested yet if interface is also labeled), but I just would be happier that I don't need to put setters/getters to every inherited class.

Will there be performance decrease when there will be millions of nodes? And I repeat I won't use that label for queries. 2 billion limit may be big enough, so I could just forget this.

Comment: appId is better to be @Indexed(unique = true, level=INSTANCE), but that is not the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to put @NodeEntity only on your concrete classes.

Alternatively use a implementation of a TypeRepresentationStrategy that only writes a single label,

like this

https://gist.github.com/jexp/8b495cf6c6e81cc2a1c9